# Leaflet.markercluster always keep spiderfied

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

Is there a way to show always the spiderfied version of a Markercluster after a specificc zoom level with https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster or an other plugin?

When I do:

```
clusters.forEach(function(cluster) {
  cluster.spiderfy()
})
```

It will not keep them open.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/744 ?

Comment: BTW you might rather need to show the unclustered markers at a certain zoom level, unless they overlap. For that you can try `disableClusteringAtZoom` option.

Comment: That is the point I have some markers that are at the exact same point.
For now I just keep them as a cluster…